# Altering multiple tablespaces at once in Oracle

Tags: oracle, tablespaces

I need help in altering multiple tablespaces at once in Oracle Database 11g.
My particular scenario is that this command will be used in a shell script to set all of the tablespaces in read-write mode for upgrade purposes.
The problem is that each server has a different number of tablespaces, so i can't hardcode the names right in. To solve this I will make a list of all the relevant tablespaces by using the datafiles and I want to pass this list it as an argument.

For instance, you alter one tablespace as such :

```
ALTER TABLESPACE DATA1 READ ONLY;
```

I want to do something of the likes :

```
ALTER TABLESPACE DATA1,DATA2,DATA3 READ ONLY;
```

Is this possible? If so what is the exact syntax.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for the [`alter tablespace`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_3002.htm#SQLRF01002) statement only supports one tablespace at a time, you can't list more than one as you're trying to.

If you're scripting that command already, simply have your script issue multiple `alter tablespace` statements rather than one.

If you're generating your list of tablespaces from `dba_tablespaces`, you can dynamically alter the tablespaces from that with something like:

```
begin
  for tbs in (select tablespace_name from dba_tablespaces where [your conditions])
  loop
    execute immediate 'alter tablespace '||tbs.tablespace_name||' read only';
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: Your solution worked for me. Thank you for the help!